# Error: Connection terminated unexpectedly in botpress 12

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript

[image]

I am using Botpress 12 for an open-source chatbot project. However, I am facing an issue where I encounter an error every 2-3 days. To temporarily resolve this problem, I have to restart the server. Unfortunately, this is not a permanent solution. It's important to note that the error only occurs in the production environment, while the development mode works perfectly fine. I need assistance in resolving this issue permanently.